# Is sshd UseLogin enabled or disabled by default?

Tags: ssh, cve

This question relates to CVE-2015-8325.

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2015-8325

Comment: My guess would be: it depends on the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UseLogin` option is disabled by default in OpenSSH for many years and I don't know about any distribution that would like to use this fail-prone and limited method of authentication, when there are much better implemented in OpenSSH (PAM, ...).

Therefore the resolution in RHEL -- the packages are affected, but not vulnerable with default (and sane) configuraiton.